# No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of ‘==’

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm trying to write an Eq instance for this data type:

```
data Tree a b = Leaf b | Node a (Tree a b) (Tree a b)
deriving (Show)
```

I wrote the trivial code I thought that would work:

```
instance Eq (Tree a b) where
  (Leaf x) == (Leaf y) =  x == y
  (Node val1 l1 r1) == (Node val2 l2 r2)  =  (val1 == val2) && (l1==l2) && (r1==r2)
  _  == _  = False
```

But then I get the error:

```
• No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of ‘==’
  Possible fix: add (Eq a) to the context of the instance declaration
• In the first argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘(val1 == val2)’
  In the expression: (val1 == val2) && (l1 == l2) && (r1 == r2)
  In an equation for ‘==’:
     (Node val1 l1 r1) == (Node val2 l2 r2)
     = (val1 == val2) && (l1 == l2) && (r1 == r2)
```

I've tried adding `Eq a => ...` but then I get the same error for type `b`. And I can't seem to add `Eq b` as well.

Any help will be appreciated, 10x!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have written, you have to put type constraints `Eq a` and `Eq b`. You just have to put the constraints in parentheses and separate them with comma.

```
instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (Tree a b) where
  (Leaf x) == (Leaf y) =  x == y
  (Node val1 l1 r1) == (Node val2 l2 r2)  =  (val1 == val2) && (l1==l2) && (r1==r2)
  _  == _  = False
```

Answer (score 6):

You write an instance where you call the `(==)` function on instances of `a` and `b`:

```
instance Eq (Tree a b) where
  (Leaf x) == (Leaf y) = x == y
  (Node val1 l1 r1) == (Node val2 l2 r2) = (val1 == val2) && (l1==l2) && (r1==r2)
  _  == _  = False
```

But `x` and `y` in your first clause are instances of `a`, and `val1` and `val2` in your second clause are instances of `b`. It is *not* said that you can compare those. For example you can not check equality of two functions (it is fundamentally impossible in computer science to check if two functions are equal in general). As a result in that case we can never derive whether the two trees are equal.

Anyway, Haskell notices that you use the function [**`(==) :: Eq c => c -> c -> Bool`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-61--61-) with as operands `x` and `y` (in the first clause), and hence `Eq a`, is required. The same reasoning holds for the second clause: we see that you call `(==)`, with two `b` instances, so `Eq b` is required. We need to add those type constraints to the `instance` declaration:

```
instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (Tree a b) where
  (Leaf x) == (Leaf y) = x == y
  (Node val1 l1 r1) == (Node val2 l2 r2) = (val1 == val2) && (l1==l2) && (r1==r2)
  _  == _  = False
```

As a consequence, you can only check equality of two trees, given the `a` and `b` of the tree are types that are an instance of the `Eq` typeclass. But that is logical, since if you can for instance not compare the values of the `Leaf`s, then how can you say whether a tree is equal or not?